# Selenium WebDriver Chrome change fake video device name

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is a problem when you use video substitution, the device is defined as a video title file.

That is:

```
options.add_argument("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream")
options.add_argument("--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=video_camera.y4m")
```

device name 'video_camera.y4m'
The documentation says https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ That two types of files can be used "mjpeg" or "y4m"

But you can't use a symlink, for example. I.e. you need to change the path to the file to a file without an extension.

What options can I use?